Reading shapefiles: Can only read the geometry
I have a function which reads various shapefiles as follows:
def read_gdf(file:str,crs:str,current_crs:str)->gpd.GeoDataFrame:
    
    collection = list(fiona.open(file,'r',  encoding='iso-8859-1'))       
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(collection)               
    df1['isvalid'] = df1['geometry'].apply(lambda x: isvalid(x))
    df1 = df1[df1['isvalid'] == 1]
    collection = json.loads(df1.to_json(orient='records'))            
    return gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(collection, crs=current_crs).to_crs(crs)

gdf = read_gdf(file, crs,current_crs=current_crs)

The columns of the output are as follows:
Index(['geometry', 'titref', 'nature', 'num', 'indice', 'complement', 'type']

I use exactly the same function and exactly the same inputs in a different script but strangely I get different results.
I get an error as follows:
KeyError: "['nature', 'num', 'indice', 'complement', 'titref'] not in index"

I seems that I can only read geometries which is very strange. Can someone comment?

Why dont you use gpd.read_file?

Because I get a lot of invalid geometries. Thats why i use this function. Is there a way to rewrite this?

If the geometries are corrupt, it isn't really a shapefile so much as a file with a .shp suffix and some of the same formatting as a shapefile. Undefined behavior is the expected outcome from bad data. You need to address the source of the bad data.

Can you read_file and then repair the geometries?

Yes that sounds like an option. I will try it

When I try gpd.read_file I get an error ValueError: A LinearRing must have at least 3 coordinate tuples
